# Problem with multiple graphql resolver implementations in nestjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, nestjs

I just started learning NestJS and GraphQL.  I started with a single resolver class `UserResolver` defined in `UserModule`.  This class provides methods to read a list of users or a specific user.  Methods are decorated with `@Query()`, a `user.graphql`file is provided, GraphQL is initialized in `AppModule`, all as described in the docs.  All works well, I can get a list of users or specific user through Insomnia Tool or through Playground.  I am happy!

Now I have created a second module, `RoleModule`.  I created a `role.graphql` file and a `RoleResolver` class, I basically replicated all the work done for `User` but this time for `Role`.  The GraphQL type definition for type `Role` as well as the Query definitions in the `role.graphql` file are recognized.  What is not recognized are my `Query()` implementations in the `RoleResolver` class, they are not getting invoked.

If I put all these `Role` related `@Query()` definitions into the `UserResolver` class, these `Role` related queries are now getting invoked.

Is that expected behavior?  Do I need to put all my GraphQL query definitions into a single class?  Is it possible to spread NestJS-GraphQL resolver implementations over several modules?  Am I doing something wrong?  Please help.

Comment: This works for me. Have you declared the resolver in your modules `providers` array? Is the name in the `@Query('role')` correct? Also make sure that you import `Query` from `@nestjs/graphql` and __not__ from `@nestjs/common`. If this does not help, please include the source code for the role resolver.

Comment: @KimKern: Thanks for your help.  I did import from `@nestjs/common`, that was the problem...  Sometimes a second pair of eyes are quite helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you import `Query` from `@nestjs/graphql` and **not** from `@nestjs/common`.